# Issue mocking argparse with unittest

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have client code that I need to test

```
def arg_parser(arg_parse=None):
    if not arg_parse:
        arg_parse = sys.argv[1:]
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--a', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--b', type=str, required=True)
    return parser.parse_args(arg_parse)

def main():
      arg_parse = arg_parser()
      update_config(arg_parse)
      ......

def update_config(conf_args: argparse):
    # read default YAML configuration file
    with open('resources/config.yaml', 'r') as file:
        conf = yaml.safe_load(file.read())
    # Updated the YAML configuration file
    if conf_args.a: // gives error here
        ..........

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And I am testing this main method by mocking the arg_parser method

```
@mock.patch('test.prepare.arg_parser')
def test_main(mock_arg_parser):
    args = arg_parser(['--a', 'a1',
                       '--b', 'b1'])

    mock_arg_parser.return_value = args
    ...
    main()
```

But I am getting an exception when I try to access arguments from argparse (`arg_parse.a`)

```
        # read default YAML configuration file
        with open('resources/config.yaml', 'r') as file:
            conf = yaml.safe_load(file.read())
        # Updated the YAML configuration file
>       if conf_args.a:
          AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Unfortunately, I can't align client code so need to fix the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out you don't need to involve mocking at all -- you can simplify your code as follows:

```py
def arg_parser(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--a', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--b', type=str, required=True)
    return parser.parse_args(arg_parse)

def main(argv: Sequence[str] | None = None):
      arg_parse = arg_parser(argv)
      update_config(arg_parse)
      ......

def update_config(conf_args: argparse):
    # read default YAML configuration file
    with open('resources/config.yaml', 'r') as file:
        conf = yaml.safe_load(file.read())
    # Updated the YAML configuration file
    if conf_args.a: # gives error here
        ..........

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and then in your test pass through the argument list explicitly:

```py
def test_main():
    main(['--a', 'a1', '--b', 'b1'])
```

no need for a complicated mocking!

this works because `argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args` defaults to `sys.argv[1:]` when passed `None` (as happens in your script by default) but you can pass your testing arguments for your test!  I go over this technique [in a video I made](https://youtu.be/sv46294LoP8)